# Which way to implement this picture in HTML CSS code and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a situation to develop a code similaire of the picture above.

if some one can provide me an implmentation to orgnise this using HTML and CSS

I tried with boostrap div and col and native HTML using table,tr and td and I found it difficult

[image]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg i-circle"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="label-font">n° d'appel</p> <br />
      <p class="val-font">04444444</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried

Comment: about table, you may read this https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/ & https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using CSS grids. Here is an example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.icon {
  grid-row: span 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="icon"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg i-circle"></i></p>
  <p class="label-font">n° d'appel</p>
  <p class="val-font">04444444</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use flexbox, it's the easiest way. Tables are not used for layout but to display data in a readable form.

Read more: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You should also check Font Awesome docs because the correct class to use in v5 is `fas` not `fa`: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

```css
/*DEMO*/body{padding:3rem}
.wrap{display:flex;align-items:center}
.fa-phone{margin-right:1rem}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <i class="fas fa-lg fa-phone"></i>
  <div>
      <div>n° d'appel</div>
      <div>04444444</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.min.js"></script>
```